# Proper use of Invoke-Expression?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I've just recently completed my first nightly build script (first significant anything script, really) in powershell.  I seem to have things working well, if not yet robustly (I haven't handled significant error-checking yet), but I found myself falling into an idiom around the `Invoke-Expression` cmdlet, and I'm wondering if I'm using it properly.

Specifically, I use a series of variables to build up command-lines that I will use to build the solution, then run the solution's unit tests.  e.g., something like:

```
$tmpDir = "C:\Users\<myuser>\Development\Autobuild"
$solutionPath=$tmpDir+"\MyProj\MyProj.sln"
$devenv="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\common7\ide\devenv"
$releaseProfile="Release"
$releaseCommandLine="`"$devenv`" `"$solutionPath`" /build `"$releaseProfile`""
```

This works well enough, `$releaseCommandLine` contains the command line that I want to execute when I'm done.  I then execute it via this line:

```
$output = Invoke-Expression "& $releaseCommandLine"
```

Is this the proper way to execute a manually-built command line from a powershell script?  I thought initially that `Invoke-Command` would do it, but I must have been doing something wrong because I couldn't get that working at all for half an hour, and I got this working almost immediately.

I've followed this same pattern a few other times in this same script.  Is this a best-practice?

Comment: I had similar problems when trying to run visual studio. I ended up with Start-Process from PowerShell Community Extensions. Or you can try [System.Diagnostics.Process] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.process.aspx )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks fine to me.  Only thing I'd change is to use more Powershell features in place of fragile assumptions.  E.g.:

- use Join-Path instead of string concatenation
- use the `Env:\` provider to look up the `%programfiles(x86)%` dir (or better yet, use the `HKML:\` provider to find the path - it's in SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\\InstallDir)
- when I have to write a string that contains literal doublequotes **and** variable expansion, I usually fall back to the syntax below.  Personal preference, obviously.

  ```
  '"{0}" "{1}" /build "{2}"' -f $devenv, $solutionPath, $releaseProfile
  ```

In some cases I'd be inclined to use Process.Start() so that I could capture the stdout & stderr streams independently (and maybe even control stdin interactively, depending on the application).

PS - the '&' is not strictly necessary.

Comment: Wouldn't `$devenv $solutionpath /build $releaseprofile` work as well, simple and straightforward? I mean, there's no real reason why one would have to explicitly write quotes here, if everything that can contain spaces is within strings anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll see what I can integrate.  Didn't know that Join-Path even existed, e.g.  :)

Comment: @Johannes:  I recall getting some problems because of the spaces in the paths when the expression was actually invoked.

Comment: @Johannes: if the string becomes 'devenv.exe c:\solution path\file.sln /build Release' how will devenv.exe know that it's supposed to represent 3 arguments instead of 4?

Comment: Richard, if put into `Invoke-Expression`, yes. I made a mistake, though, you have to call `$devenv` with `.$devenv`. All *arguments* however, are going to be quoted anyway, this is done automatically by PowerShell for you. When you pass a variable to a program as argument, it will be expanded to a string and properly quoted. You can easily test this with a small program that just prints its arguments.

Comment: Cool - I didn't know you could "dot source" an EXE.

Comment: I never really understood how the `.` operator actually works, I just tried :-)

Answer (score 10):

I think it is unnecessary to use Invoke-Expression here.  I've done this with a lot of build scripts and it usually looks like this:

```
$vsroot = "$env:ProgramFiles(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0"
$devenv = "$vsroot\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
$sln = Join-Path <source_root> Source\MyProj\MyProj.sln
& $devenv $sln /build Release
```

or

```
& $devenv $sln /build "Release|Any CPU"
```

Although lately, I have had some troubles with using devenv.exe (mis-behaving add-ins, etc), so now I use msbuild.exe:

```
$msbuild = 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe'
& $msbuild $sln /p:Configuration=Release
```

Currently MSBuild can handle C#, VB and C++ (invokes vcbuild) but it can't handle solutions with setup & deployment projects in them.  However, I have found it to be more reliable than using devenv.exe.

BTW you typically need to invoke other tools (sn.exe, signtool.exe, mt.exe, etc) in a build script that are specific to the version of Visual Studio/.NET you want to build against.  So it is usually best to configure your environment variables in the same way that the VS 2008 command prompt does.  With the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) installed, you can enable one line in the PSCX profile header to enable this for .NET 3.5/VS 2008 settings:

```
$Pscx:Preferences["ImportVisualStudioVars"] = $true
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply on my twitter the other day, Keith.  That pdf clued me in to some useful stuff, especially re: changes from v1 to v2.  :)

Comment: As mentioned in my comment, Invoke-Expression and & are basically synonyms; you never need both.  Some people like to be verbose in scripts (eg writing out ForEach-Object in place of %).  But I personally prefer your way :)

Comment: "$env:ProgramFiles(x86)" doesn't work.  It returns "C:\Program Files(x86)" instead of "C:\Program Files (x86)".  Yet "dir env:" shows ProgramFiles(x86) with the space.

Comment: I was able to work around the issue by using "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}"